# How to collect the last 5 notifications that were created using angularjs-toaster?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, notifications, angularjs-service

I am currently trying to create a table with the last 5 notifications that were created using angularjs-toaster (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-toaster). I understand this service fairly well, but I have not been able to find an answer if it is possible to get access to past toasts that were "shooted". With this the user could be able to see his/her last notifications. This is how I defined the toasts If it helps.

```
$rootScope.notify = function(type, message,title, timeout) {
    // function to pic timeout
    function pick(arg, def) {
        return (typeof arg === undefined ? def : arg);
    }

    timeout = pick(timeout, 5000);
    toaster.pop({
        type: type,
        body: message,
        title:title,
        timeout: timeout,
    });
};
```

Comment: You need to store the notification every time it is fired in a database and show the top 5 from it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? You don’t know how to store in database or you don’t know when to?

Comment: just create some array and push the toaster config to this array

Comment: I have no idea how to store a notification. Im new with programming. Do I need to introduce some data base engine?